# In ggplot2, plot multiple geom_lines using distinct row names to identify them

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I promise this post is less confusing than the title.

**Background:**

I have a `dataframe` that's the result of an `rbind` of several years' of survey data about health insurance, all with the exact same variables. In this case, the `characteristic` being detailed is "type of health insurance", and each row has an `estimate` of the proportion with that insurance type, along with an `lower_95` and `upper_95` entry to represent the lower and upper bounds of a 95% confidence interval (CI). Here's the df:

```
df <- data.frame(characteristic = c("Private", "Public", "Uninsured", "Private", "Public", "Uninsured", "Private", "Public", "Uninsured"),
                 estimate =       c(70.800, 25.5,   3.7 , 73.8,  20.56, 5.64 , 69.67, 23.91, 6.42),
                 lower_95 =       c(63.530, 18.140, 1.24, 68.09, 15.34, 2.62 ,  62.4, 17.84, 2.55),
                 upper_95 =       c(78.00 , 32.90,  6.2,  79.5,  25.78, 8.66 , 76.9 , 30.0 , 10.3),
                 year     =       c(1996,   1996,  1996 , 1997,  1997 ,  1997 , 1998, 1998 , 1998),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**The problem:**

As you can see, the variable `characteristic` contains the 3 different insurance types, repeated 3 times each. I'd like each insurance type to have its own `geom_line`, based on `estimate`, across each of its 3 observations -- one obs. for each `year` 1996-1998.

The problem is that I can get this working for one line in a sort of crude and ad-hoc way like so:

```
ggplot(data = df[str_detect(df$characteristic, "Private"), ], aes(x = year)) + ###
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95), fill = "lightgray", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = estimate), linetype = 1)
```

[image: ggplot attempt]

But I can't get the other lines in there.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried specifying the separate `geom_line`s like so:

```
ggplot(aes(x = year)) + ###
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95), fill = "lightgray", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = df[str_detect(df$characteristic, "Private"), ], aes(y = estimate), linetype = 1) +
  geom_line(data = df[str_detect(df$characteristic, "Public"), ], aes(y = estimate), linetype = 1) +
  geom_line(data = df[str_detect(df$characteristic, "Uninsured"), ], aes(y = estimate), linetype = 1)
```

But that gets me an error - I'm guessing the first line of `ggplot` requires a data specification.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by mapping `characteristic` on the `group` aesthetic which will give you one line and one ribbon for each `characteristic`:

```r
df <- data.frame(characteristic = c("Private", "Public", "Uninsured", "Private", "Public", "Uninsured", "Private", "Public", "Uninsured"),
                 estimate =       c(70.800, 25.5,   3.7 , 73.8,  20.56, 5.64 , 69.67, 23.91, 6.42),
                 lower_95 =       c(63.530, 18.140, 1.24, 68.09, 15.34, 2.62 ,  62.4, 17.84, 2.55),
                 upper_95 =       c(78.00 , 32.90,  6.2,  79.5,  25.78, 8.66 , 76.9 , 30.0 , 10.3),
                 year     =       c(1996,   1996,  1996 , 1997,  1997 ,  1997 , 1998, 1998 , 1998),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, group = characteristic)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95), fill = "lightgray", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = estimate, ), linetype = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Followup question: what if my `df` had >3 types of entry in `characteristic`, but I still only wanted to use the 3 I mentioned in this example (private, public, uninsured)? In other words, how could I specify a partial list of characteristics for the `group` aesthetic?

Comment: In that case filter your dataset before passing in to ggplot, i.e. use e.g. `data = subset(df, df$characteristic %in% c("Private", ...))`

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward as the data is already in a great format for use with ggplot.
By adding `characteristic` as a group you will get a line for each, then in the `geom_line` you could add it as a color aswell.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(characteristic = c("Private", "Public", "Uninsured", "Private", "Public", "Uninsured", "Private", "Public", "Uninsured"),
                 estimate =       c(70.800, 25.5,   3.7 , 73.8,  20.56, 5.64 , 69.67, 23.91, 6.42),
                 lower_95 =       c(63.530, 18.140, 1.24, 68.09, 15.34, 2.62 ,  62.4, 17.84, 2.55),
                 upper_95 =       c(78.00 , 32.90,  6.2,  79.5,  25.78, 8.66 , 76.9 , 30.0 , 10.3),
                 year     =       c(1996,   1996,  1996 , 1997,  1997 ,  1997 , 1998, 1998 , 1998),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, group = characteristic)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95), fill = "lightgray", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = estimate, color = characteristic), linetype = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted version:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(year = year(ymd(year, truncated = 2L)))
         
         
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(year), group = characteristic)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95), fill = "lightgray", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = estimate, color = characteristic), linetype = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = estimate, color = characteristic)) +
  theme_pubclean()
```

[image]

Comment: This is great; didn't know about the pubclean theme. Question: why specify `factor(year)` ?

Comment: If you remove `factor()` you will see the difference.